# mCustomScrollbar scroll bottom

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll, scrollbar

I have an issue with mCustomScrollbar, here's my code but it won't work.

```
function createChat(){
    $("#chatview").load("chat/refresh.php",function(){
        $(this).mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", "bottom");
    });
}

$(window).load(function(){
    setInterval("createChat()",9000);
    createChat();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try attaching the plugin to the chat view element:

```
//cache variable
var $chatView = $("#chatview");

function createChat(){
    $chatView.load("chat/refresh.php",function(){
       $chatView.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", "bottom");
    });
}

$(window).load(function(){
    setInterval("createChat()",9000);
    createChat();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution but it's still not working :) cannot realize why :)